# C# code for dividing text into columns

Tags: c#, multiple-columns, divide

I want to seperate txt data by " " (space character) with c# code. Data is seen in the below. I want there to be columns and reach all the columns seperately. For example copying 3rd and 4th columns of 3rd, 4th and 5th rows. A lot of codes are tried but not working. 
I searched the web and i can't run the codes that i found. 
How can i do that?

data inside the text.txt file

1
41
973    3.93E-03    9.99E-02    2.00E+01    3.90E-01    0.00E+00    0.00E+00
975    7.85E-03    9.97E-02    2.00E+01    3.90E-01    0.00E+00    0.00E+00
977    1.18E-02    9.93E-02    2.00E+01    3.90E-01    0.00E+00    0.00E+00
979    1.56E-02    9.88E-02    2.00E+01    3.89E-01    0.00E+00    0.00E+00
981    1.95E-02    9.81E-02    2.00E+01    3.88E-01    0.00E+00    0.00E+00
983    2.33E-02    9.72E-02    2.00E+01    3.87E-01    0.00E+00    0.00E+00

Comment: No code no help. If you can't run the codes you found on web you should learn basics first.

Comment: Please specify exactly what you tried and what did not work. If you encounter error messages, mention them in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
var fileContent = File.ReadAllLines("data.txt");
var separated = fileContent.Select(line => line.Split(' ').ToArray();
```

You'll end up with array (rows) of values (columns). To access them use:

```
var row4Col5 = separated[3][4];
```

Not that you might want to do some boundaries checks, as some lines of your data file don't contain all columns.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily read the whole text file into an array of strings:

```
string[] content = File.ReadAllLines("{path to your file");
```

And then skip the first 2 lines which are not relevant in this case and divide each line into an array of values:

```
string[][] array = content.Skip(2).Select(line => line.Split(' ')).ToArray();
```